# Delay in ofstream::open, possibly due to mixing with _iobuf?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a C++ program that creates an output file "A" with ofstream.  This file is then read by some legacy C code that opens the file with _iobuf.  The legacy code then creates its own output file "B" using _iobuf, and this file is then read by the C++ program using ifstream.  This sequence is iterated many times, with the same file names for A and B in each iteration.

Occasionally, the C++ program cannot open the output file A for writing, and I must try several times before it succeeds.  This occurs nondeterministically, and maybe once in a thousand iterations.  Note that the C program never has to wait to open its input or output file, nor does the C++ program ever have to wait to open its input file.  This informal observation is based on hundreds of thousands of iterations.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with mixing ofstream and _iobuf in the same program?  Both the C++ code and the C code are linked into the same program.  And the legacy C code is technically C++ code, but was written in a very C-like style.  Is there anything I can do to eliminate this waiting to open the ofstream file?  I do not want to change the legacy code if I can possibly avoid it.

Pseudo code (not compiled):

```
void someObject::someMethod()
{
    for (int count = 0; count < someLimit; ++count)
    {
        newerObject::firstMethod();
        olderObject::secondMethod();
        newerObject::thirdMethod();
    }
}

void newerObject::firstMethod()
{
    // do some processing first

    // then write the results of the processing to a file
    ofstream A;
    A.open("A", ofstream::out); // this sometimes must be tried multiple times
    // write data to file A
    A.close();
}

void olderObject::secondMethod()
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("A", "rt"); // this always works the first time
    // read data from file A
    fclose(f);

    // do some processing

    f = fopen("B", "w");
    // write data to file B
    fclose(f);
}

void newerObject::thirdMethod()
{
    ifstream B;
    B.open("B"); // this always works the first time
    // read data from file B
    B.close();

    // do some processing
}
```

Currently, as a work around, I put the ofstream::open in a do-while loop.  I would love to get rid of this awkwardness.  Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: Got rid of c tag, this question has nothing to do with C.

Comment: Just to be clear: the fclose preceding the problem is after only reading file A, not writing.  I don't think there's any delay due to buffering.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the problem is almost certainly not the use of different methods to access the files: under the hood, the C and C++ I/O functions use the same system I/O facilities. You seem to be using Windows (on other systems files typically can be open multiple times simultaneously) and I don't know much about the system but I would suspect that the file system hasn't been updated to reflect that the file is closed when you try to open it. This may have to do with the "t" open flag: I don't know what this is about.

On UNIXes you can force the I/O operations to wait until the actual change on disk completed. Something like this could help avoiding the problem but has the significant cost that operations become hideously slow. On UNIXes one approach would be to blow away the file system entry the moment the file was opened successfully (after all, at this point its name isn't used anymore):

```
if (FILE* fp = fopen("file", "r")) {
    remove("file");
    // do processing
}
```

However, if I recall correctly on Windows you can neither remove the file nor rename it. Personally, in solving the problem I would proceed as follows:

1. Determine under which situations the file can't be opened, e.g. by keeping the file open and trying to open it. This is mainly intended to create a setup where the problem is reproducible so you can verify later that you indeed found a solution.
2. Once I found a way to reproduce the problem I would probably a better idea of the actual root cause and possibly googling would help. In any case this is the point where researching the root cause comes in.
3. Once the cause is understood it is hopefully easy to devise a solution. If not, opening the file multiple times under it is successful may very well be the right solution.

Comment: Yes, this is running under Windows.  Compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.  I have tried to no avail to create a reproducible test case, but it remains nondeterministic from the viewpoint of the program.